# Do I really need to worry about security if I used https certificates in website?

Tags: security

Most of the time companies uses SSL/Https certificates for their sites or projects, still they always shows worries or concerns over security to development team. Isn't SSL/https sufficient for website security?

Comment: Where to start...? "Security" is the absence of mistakes. There are still plenty of stupid mistakes you can make in writing an app, even when using SSL. SSL protects only one specific aspect (transport encryption) of a whole long complicated chain of events. – It'd be fantastic if you could secure a garbage pile of an app simply by slapping an SSL certificate on it. Alas, that's not reality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisely the Answer is 'NO'.
See SSL helps you to to safeguard your users against attacks like Man in the Middle attack where an attacker sitting somewhere in the parking lot can intercept the requests made to your website by the victim who is your user.

Having SSL doesn't mean your project or website is robust. Still there are several attacks like SQL Injection, Cross site request forgery, Cross Site Scripting, Insecure Direct Object reference etc.

Hope this Helps.

Best.